# How to undo a merge of file in ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase

I was experimenting in the ClearCase merge manager and mistakenly merged one file to another file (which turned out to be parent of the file).

I want to revert it back now.

How to cancel that merge for that specific file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do, if you haven't yet completed the merge is to:

- undo checkout the merged checked out version in the destination view (the view used to make the merge)
- relaunch the merge manager.

You will see that, during the second execution of the merge manager:

- any version already merged will directly be displayed as merged
- the version you undo checked out will again be listed as to be merged.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but perhaps adding an additional detail will be useful to future users as it was to me.

In add one detaul to [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc)'s answer, I saved my merge before re-launching the merge manager, and hit **Resume** upon re-launch instead of **New**.

This approach worked as VonC said.